# unable to add the same array more than one time using addControl() in angular6

Tags: javascript, json, angular, frontend, angular6

Here is my Json:

```
{"id":"","title":"","areas":[{"areaId":"","type":"","position":"","parts":[]}]}
```

Now I want to add the `areas[]` array as many times as the user request for it,
When I use a different name Each time the array is getting inserted.
for example :

```
{"id":"","title":"","areas":[{"areaId":"","type":"","position":"","parts":[]}],"areas2":[{"areaId":"","type":"","position":"","parts":[]}],"areas3":[{"areaId":"","type":"","position":"","parts":[]}]}
```

Every Time I want the name of arary to be areas only.

here is my code for adding the array:

```
let areas = new FormArray([
    new FormGroup({
        areaId : new FormControl(''),
        type : new FormControl(''),
        position : new FormControl(''),
        parts : new FormArray([])
    })
]); 

this.form.addControl('areas', areas);
```

Comment: Do you mean to say that the name of the key you want to use is same all the time?

Comment: Dont make another FormArray, push the FormGroup in the existing FormArray

Comment: YES, the name of the key I want is 'areas' all the time

Comment: @SarthakAggarwal, I want A new array every time

Comment: In a JSON, you can have multiple keys of same name but it will take last value of the key defined, hence if you want to have same key for multiple values, declare it as an array which you have done, therefore should have value in the following format 'areas' :  [{},{},{}], You dont need to make another array of same key name.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating new form array every time. You should push to add new form control there.

```
const formGroup= new FormGroup({
        areaId : new FormControl(''),
        type : new FormControl(''),
        position : new FormControl(''),
        parts : new FormArray([])
    })

areas.push(formGroup);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **get** for create the formArray instance and push new controls in it

like this,

in `.ts`

```
 formGropup = this.formBuilder({
      areas : this.formBuilder.array([])
    })

/*Initlaize formArray*/
    get areaCollection(): FormArray {
        return this.pecRegForm.get('areas') as FormArray;
    };

 /*Initlaize formcontrols*/
    createArea(): FormGroup {
        return this.fb.group({
            areaId : new FormControl(''),
            type : new FormControl(''),
            position : new FormControl(''),
            parts : new FormArray([])
        });
    }

    /* Here you can push new formGroup*/
    addMoreAreas() {
        this.censusCollection.push(this.createArea());
    }
```

in `.html`

```
<div class="col-md-4" *ngFor="let item of formGropup.get('areas').controls; let i = index;" [formGroupName]="i">
   <input formControlName="areas" type="text" placeholder="Id"> 
   <input formControlName="type" type="text" placeholder="Id">  
   <!-- and so on -->                           
</div>
```

Comment: Just Confused with How can I bind these dynamic Group to my template